# Why does this Maven Java project show this error page?

Tags: java, maven

I see an error page and I don't know why. This is a Maven project and it works succesfully, but I see this error page.

The LoginRegister project shows an error, also the error is shown in the Java resources folder but it isn't shown in any java or jsp files and the app works successfully. But I try to understand why does the project show this error. Any feedback will be apreciated!

[image]

Comment: Can't you just put your mouse hover and see the details ? Or tell us the sentence associated to

Comment: Does the Problems tab show anything ?

Comment: Since it seems to be Eclipse, go to "Window">>"Show view">>"Problems", this tab  may give you more details about the errors.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I resolved the problem... the error was: "Java compiler level does not match the version of the installed Java project facet" because I changed the compiler version from 1.5 to 1.7 to use String in switch case. Now I changed it back to 1.5 and the error disappear.